# Is that OK to use the MRO in order to override a mixin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, mixins

**Problem description:** I have a class `C` inheriting from mixins `A` and `B`.
I want a new class, `C_`, having all the methods/attributes defined in the class `C` but with `B` swapped with `B_` (same API) in the inheritance scheme (one possible use of this is easy mocking). **All classes are new style classes.**

I got what I wanted by messing with the inheritance order, therefore the MRO:

```
A   B   B_    B_  A   B
 \ /   /       \   \ /
  C   /         \   C
   \ /           \ /
    C1            C2
C1(C,B_)       C2(B_,C)

C1.__mro__ = (C1, C , A, B, B_, object)
C2.__mro__ = (C2, B_, C, A, B , object)
```

The `C2` method (inheriting the modified mixin before the `C` class) works without much surprise and if I call a method defined in the `B` mixin, the `B_`'s definition is chosen.

For the moment it works, but I feel like: "fingers crossed, I hope a special case does not arise and break the system !"

**The question is**: is it a finally-not-so-wrong way to solve the problem or is there a better way to do it ?

PS: I think I could take my bazooka and create a metaclass to redefine the mro ([as said in the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro)), but my instinct says it's not going to be necessarily prettier.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. The algorithm used to build the MRO is documented, and, as such, you can rely on the order you are seeing.

Comment: Note: if B_ inherits from B, it will precede B in the MRO whatever the order in the class definition. This is not your use case, but it might be the case for someone searching about this, so I thought it might be worth mentioning. I can understand why B_ would not inherit from B but note that you don't exactly replace B with B_: methods defined in B and not in B_ are still taken from B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach should work just fine.  It is legitimate to use a subclass to control the MRO and to shadow one class with another.

This blog post gives several examples:  https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 0):

You already know this is messy.  If A and B (and hence B') were to have attributes in common, then C would get those attributes from A while C_ would get them from B_.

Assuming that you are not using super() in any new methods defined in C, I would make C a simple class (no bases) and then write

```
class D(C, A, B): pass
class D_(C, A, B_): pass
```